# Как подогнать изображение под размер под picturebox с сохранением пропорций?

Tags: c#, winforms, form, picturebox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал небольшую программу, которая отрисовывает графы и кидает изображение в picture box, но если граф слишком большой, то он уходит за экран. А если использовать

```
pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

то изображение сильно растягивается.
Если возможность подгонять изображение, чтобы пропорции оставались нормальными(уменьшать, если слишком большое)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сохранение пропорций - `PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom`

Comment: работает, спасибо!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так может ответом?